# C++ console window flashes then dissapears

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, executable

Ok so here is a sales tax calculator I made and the console window flashes then disappears. Just wondering what I did wrong. Also I feel like a unit test is embedded in the code itself but I was wondering how a unit test would apply to parameters such as these.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void p(double x)
{
  cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << x;
}

int main()
{
  ifstream basketFile;
 basketFile.open("basket.txt");

int howMany;
double price;
double salesTax = 0;
double total = 0;
bool correct = true;

string printIt;
string second;

string garbage1;
string garbage2;
string garbage3;
string garbage4;

string whichImported;

while(!basketFile.eof())
{
    //how many of the specific item do you have?
    basketFile >> howMany;

    //what is the item?
    basketFile >> printIt;

    cout << howMany << " ";

    if(printIt == "book")
    {
        basketFile >> garbage1; //throw away "at"

        basketFile >> price; //get price of book

        total += price;

        cout << printIt;
        cout << " ";
        cout << garbage1;
        cout << " ";
        p(price);
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if(printIt == "music")
    {
        basketFile >> garbage1; //throw away "CD"
        basketFile >> garbage2; //throw away "at"

        basketFile >> price;

        salesTax = ((10)*price)/100;

        price += salesTax;
        total += price;

        cout << printIt;
        cout << " ";
        cout << garbage1;
        cout << " ";
        cout << garbage2;
        cout << " ";
        p(price);
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if(printIt == "chocolate")
    {
        basketFile >> garbage1;
        basketFile >> garbage2;

        basketFile >> price;



        cout << printIt;
        cout << " ";
        cout << garbage1;
        cout << " ";
        cout << garbage2;
        cout << " ";
        p(price);
        cout << endl;
    }
    else if(printIt == "imported")
    {
        basketFile >> second;

        if(second == "box")
        {
            basketFile >> garbage1;
            basketFile >> garbage2;
            basketFile >> garbage3;

            basketFile >> price;

            cout << printIt;
            cout << " ";
            cout << second;
            cout << " ";
            cout << garbage1;
            cout << " ";
            cout << garbage2;
            cout << " ";
            cout << garbage3;
            cout << " ";
            p(price);
            cout << endl;

            salesTax += (5)*(price)/100;

            total += price;
        }
        else
        {
            basketFile >> garbage1;
            basketFile >> garbage2;
            basketFile >> garbage3;

            basketFile >> price;

            cout << printIt;
            cout << " ";
            cout << second;
            cout << " ";
            cout << garbage1;
            cout << " ";
            cout << garbage2;
            cout << " ";
            cout << garbage3;
            cout << " ";
            p(price);
            cout << endl;

            salesTax += ((15)*price)/100;

            total += price;
        }
    }
    else if(printIt == "packet")
    {
        basketFile >> garbage1;
        basketFile >> garbage2;
        basketFile >> garbage3;
        basketFile >> garbage4;

        basketFile >> price;

        cout << printIt;
        cout << " ";
        cout << garbage1;
        cout << " ";
        cout << garbage2;
        cout << " ";
        cout << garbage3;
        cout << " ";
        cout << garbage4;
        cout << " ";
        p(price);
        cout << endl;

        total += price;
    }
    else if(printIt == "bottle")
    {
        basketFile >> garbage1;
        basketFile >> garbage2;
        basketFile >> garbage3;

        basketFile >> price;

        cout << printIt;
        cout << " ";
        cout << garbage1;
        cout << " ";
        cout << garbage2;
        cout << " ";
        cout << garbage3;
        cout << " ";
        p(price);
        cout << endl;

        salesTax += (10)*(price)/100;

        total += price;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nIncorrect parameters." << endl;
        correct = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(correct)
{
    total += salesTax;

    cout << "Sales Taxes: ";
    printf("%.1f",salesTax);
    cout << 0 << endl;
    cout << "Total: ";
    p(total);
    cout << endl;

}
else
{
     return 0;
 }
}
```

Comment: you running from debug in vs20xx? Try Ctrl+F5 it will pause before it closes (even if it crashes) or put a break point on the return in main.

Comment: Running it from the command line also works.

Comment: I would like it to run as a executable just by pointing and clicking on it. and stay open until the user wants to close it.

Answer (score 4):

By "flashing" I assume you mean the `Console` pops up, your application is run and then it closes automatically. This is normal behavior.

Add a line to fetch input from the user and the window will remain open until the input is given. Like a "press any key to close".

If you launch your application from the `Command Line`, you will see that when the execution is over, control is given back to the `Command Line` right away, that's what's making the Window close, your process is done.

The suggested tricks of using breakpoints are also viable if you just want to see what was output before closing the app.

You are asking for a code example, the easiest would probably be to

```
#include <conio.h>
```

At the beginning, and then, before your last `}`

```
_getch(); // getch() might be deprecated with your compiler
```

Comment: I need an example of how it would look in my code

Comment: @MichaelReynolds you have many examples here: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/iw6AC542/ For simple examples I will usually use `getch();`

Answer (score 1):

you can use at the end of your application:

```
char x;
cin >> x;
```

or use old C function getch() from conio.h
program will wait for press by you any key